# How to display data of two table

Tags: php, html

I have two tables in database and i want to show data from two table in the format shown in image.
[image: Format]

and tables are

### Table 1:

### id | name

1 | Heading1
 2 | Heading2

### Table2:

### id |q_name|table1_id

1 | test1  | 1
 2 | test2  | 1
 3 | test3  | 2
 4 | test4  | 2

i used foreach loop to display data of table2.

below is my code.

```
$catgquestions=Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [q_name] => test1 [table1_id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [q_name] => test2 [table1_id] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [q_name] => test3 [table1_id] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [q_name] => test4 [table1_id] => 2 ) )

<?php foreach ($catgquestions as $catgquestionss) { ?>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input  type="hidden" id="catques" name="catques[]" 
                 value=" <?php echo $catgquestionss['id']; ?>" > 
                <label for="catname" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">
                <?php echo $catgquestionss['q_name'];?>
            </label>
         </div>
<?php } ?>
```

But i could not find a solution to show the data from table1.

Can anyone provide a best solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any code related to calling your database, and that is important for your question.  Did you omit any code?

Comment: in $catgquestionss i am getting the data from table2

Comment: do you have issue retrieving data from database ?

Comment: not getting issue in retrieving data but how to show in this format which i have shown in image, i am not getting this

Comment: what is the output of $catgquestions ?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [q_name] => test1 [table1_id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [q_name] => test2 [table1_id] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [q_name] => test3 [table1_id] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [q_name] => test4 [table1_id] => 2 ) )  Output of $catgquestions

Comment: You have use two loop for your requirement.   One Loop will be for Table one and you will display name then inside loop one  second loop will start. you will display q_name.hopefully you requirement will be fulfilled.

Comment: I used this data is showing me like this                                                 
Heading1
test1
test2
test3
test4
Heading2
test1
test2
test3
test4                                                                                                                        all q_name in heading1 and heading 2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to join your table 2 with table 1 to get the heading like this

```
SELECT t2.id,t2.q_name,t1.name FROM Table2 AS t2 INNER JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t2.table1_id = t1.id ORDER BY t1.name ASC
```

Note: change the names as per your requirements

your result would be like this

```
$catgquestions=Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [q_name] => test1 [name] => Heading1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [q_name] => test2 [name] => Heading1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [q_name] => test3 [name] => Heading2 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [q_name] => test4 [name] => Heading2 ) )
```

so using a single loop you can produce the expected output like this without any formatting

```
<?php 
$heading = '';
foreach ($catgquestions as $catgquestionss) {

    if ($catgquestionss['name'] != $heading) {
        // your heading code here
        echo $catgquestionss['name'];
        $heading = $catgquestionss['name'];
    }
     // your exiting code here
     echo $catgquestionss['q_name'];
} 
?>
```

Note: do make necessary adjustments to the code but you will get the general idea from this answer.